# How to run GlassFish as Windows service?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, glassfish

I already saw the http://www.ryandelaplante.com/rdelaplante/entry/creating_a_windows_service_for link, but it doesn't appear to work on GlassFish v3.  If anyone's successfully gotten GlassFish v3 to run as a service on Windows, please share how you did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Kenai works!  http://projectkenai.com/projects/winsw/pages/Home

Answer (score 1):

In Glassfish 3 you can do this if I am not mistaken:

```
asadmin create-service
```